# Find the last occurrence of a string in a file

Tags: c#

I need to take the last occurrence of a trace of a log, from a specific string in C#, some like:

```
lines = File.ReadLines(logPath)
        .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("param"))
        .Take(20);
```

that code works, but it returns 20 lines from the first occurrence of "param" in the log, and I need the last one.

Comment: `I need the last one.`-What does it mean? Last 1 or Last 20?

Comment: The last 20 after the last ocurrence of "param".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a (extension) method which traverses source sequence backwards until it finds item matching some predicate. While you are searching for match keep stack of items which you have looked at, and then just return them if the match was found:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SkipUntilLast<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>();

    foreach(var item in source.Reverse())
    {
        if (predicate(item))
            return stack;

        stack.Push(item);
    }

    return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

Usage:

```
lines = File.ReadLines(logPath).
        .SkipUntilLast(line => line.Contains("param"))
        .Take(20);
```

Note that `Reverse` would put source sequence in the buffer, and then the stack will do similar thing (depends whether last match closer to tail or to head of source). You can use a queue of required size to keep items which you checked, thus it will have no more than 20 items in your case. You can also decide whether matched item should be included in output by moving `stack.Push` before predicate check.

---

Sample file

```
something
param foo
this
is
not
included
param bar
here
we
go
again
```

Skipping until last line containing "param" and then taking three next lines:

```
File.ReadLines("samplefile").SkipUntilLast(line => line.Contains("param")).Take(3);
```

Result:

```
[ "here", "we", "go" ]
```

Comment: this code works perfectly for what I'm looking for, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Last after converting the lines to List or Array. Like below:

```
lines = File.ReadLines(logPath)
        .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("param"))
        .ToList()
        .Last();
```

Comment: This code returns the last line of the log, after finding the desired string. It is not what I need, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To find the last occurrence of a string matching the provided predicate, I'd suggest using `LastOrDefault`:

```
File.ReadLines(logPath)       
    .LastOrDefault(line => !line.Contains("param"));
```

Otherwise, if you need the last of the `20` you've mentioned then use `Skip` and `FirstOrDefault`:

```
File.ReadLines(logPath)
    .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("param"))
    .Skip(19)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

it could also be done as:

```
File.ReadLines(logPath)
    .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("param"))
    .Take(20)
    .LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: 20 lines after last matched

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I've read it as the last match, nevertheless, I've included the solution to your comment.

Comment: this code returns the last line of the block I am looking for, but I need the complete block. Anyway thank you very much.